# Can't add new key to an object response from Mongoose

Tags: javascript, object, key, addition

I have this problem and I can't figure why.
inside a for loop I try to assign a new key value pair to each object in  an array of  objects, response from a mongoose query.
e.g.

```
    obj = {
      value1: "someValue",
      value2: [],
      value3: {}
      value4: {
        id: "someId"
      }
   }
```

if I try to do a obj.value4.newKey = "newValue" nothing seems to happen, but the thing is that when I do

```
console.log(obj.value4.newKey) // prints "newValue"
```

but when I do

```
console.log(obj)
```

or

```
console.log(obj.value4)
```

the new key added previously doesn't seems to exists

Comment: missing a comma (`,`) after `value3: {}` ....

Comment: Were you facing this problem with the data returned from mongoose queries?

Comment: @neer17 yes in did

Comment: Can you add this info to your question so that I can post a precise answer countering the problem?

Answer (score 8):

I really don't know why,  but  I've found some kind of workaround, this it what worked (continuing with the first example)

```
res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.value4));
res.newKey = "newValue";
```

now I do

```
console.log(res)
```

and I get

```
{
  id: "someId",
  newKey = "newValue"
}
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Had the exact same problem. Your solution worked for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because mongoose returns a mongoose model object (look at the screenshot):

[image: mongoose object screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Since mongoose returns mongoose model object, use .lean() function at end of the mongoose function and it will make mongoose model object to plain JavaScript object.

Hope it resolves the issue :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code:

```
obj = {
      value1: "someValue",
      value2: [],
      value3: {} // , is missing
      value4: {
        id: "someId"
      }
   }
```

And what you expecting is working for me [**See it in Action**](http://jsfiddle.net/g6fev8t6/).

Comment: sorry, I made a typo there, but anyway, this is getting weird.
if I do a 
`code`
    console.log(_.keys(obj))  
`code`
it prints all the keys in the object and I can see that the new added key exists. I can't understand why is this happen (could it be that it has something to do with "prototype" ?)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly (after fixing the missing-comma typo) - try it here with your console open, and you'll see the value for `newKey` within `value4` getting added as you'd expect:

```js
obj = {
    value1: "someValue",
    value2: [],
    value3: {},
    value4: {
        id: "someId"
    }
};

obj.value4.newKey = "newValue";
console.log(obj);
```

Whatever is wrong is not a problem with the code you've posted, but rather with the surrounding code.  Can you post a complete, executable failing example?

Comment: yeah, it has to be the environment, I cant pos't the code due to my job policies, but anyway... what could it be a possible causes ?

Comment: @flaalf: It's impossible to tell without a failing example... is the object being recreated each time round the loop?

Comment: don't know why, but  this did the job 
res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.value4));